# Where did I do this min/max problem incorrectly?

Tags: calculus

Current price of a car is \$20,000
The current price changes at a rate of $50-50\sqrt{t}$
When will the price of a new car be at a maximum?

So.... $$\frac{dp}{dt}=p'(t)=50-50\sqrt{t}$$

First, to determine where there is a min/max, I set $f'(x)=0$

*(I would then do 2nd deriv. test to determine if its a min or max)*

$$50-50\sqrt{t}=0$$
$$50=50\sqrt{t}$$
$$1=\sqrt{t}$$
$$1=t$$

However, t=1 is not a choice.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why is $t=1$ not a choice? It looks like it's the right answer: the derivative is positive before $1$ and negative afterwards. Hence the maximum is at $t=1$

Comment: If you put braces around the stuff you want under the square root sign, the top bar will extend over all of it.  \sqrt{(t)} gives $\sqrt{(t)}$.  Or, leave off the parentheses, using \sqrt t to get $\sqrt t$.  A bit prettier that way, and for more complicated expressions easier to read.

Comment: Yes, braces are better.  Fixed.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing fine.  For $t \lt 1$ the rate of change is positive, for $t \gt 1$ the rate of change is negative, so $t=1$ is the maximum.

Comment: Ok, maybe there's a typo in the solution key.  Thanks.